# Let $f:[0,a]\times[0,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Prove a version of Fubini's Theorem:

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^b\left(\int_0^af(x,y)dx\right)dy=\int_0^a\left(\int_0^bf(x,y)dy\right)dx.$$
I am given the following hint: Investigate $p:[0,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$p(t)=\int_0^t\left(\int_0^af(x,y)dx\right)dy-\int_0^a\left(\int_0^tf(x,y)dy\right)dx.$$
I have read the classical proof of Fubini's Theorem that uses $\sigma$-finite spaces, but this is beyond the scope of which this question is asked in. I am looking for advice on how to utilize the provided hint to establish a proof of this.

Comment: @mucciolo You're right, this is a duplicate...but the answer given below is a slightly different approach that could help others like me who struggled with the one you've linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p'(t)=0$, where $\dfrac{d}{dt}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(x,y)dy\right)dx=\int_{0}^{a}\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}f(x,y)dy\right)dx$ can be argued by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Another method:

Let $\varphi(t)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(x,y)dy\right)dx$, then for small $h>0$ and $t<b$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{1}{h}[\varphi(t+h)-\varphi(t)]-\int_{0}^{a}f(x,t)dx\right|&\leq\int_{0}^{a}\left(\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{t}^{t+h}|f(x,y)-f(x,t)|dy\right)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}|f(x,\eta_{t,h})-f(x,t)|dx,
\end{align*}
where $\eta_{t,h}\in[t,t+h]$, now $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,a]\times[0,b]$, this may control the last integral going to zero.

Comment: Okay, I see the general reasoning. Is there possibly a more "elementary" approach than using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: You may try Mean Value Theorem (integral version) that you may write the difference quotient and you may arrive to something like $\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+h}f(x,y)dy$, this is my rough guess, I haven't written down the formal argument, but you may try first and let's see what is going on.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I can come up with. Probably something similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578462/prove-that-int-ab-left-int-cd-fx-ydy-right-dx-int-cd-left-int-ab?rq=1 but I'm still working on understanding this.

Comment: I have just added the details, it now goes through.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Stone Weierstrass theorem: Verify that both iterated integrals give the same result for $f(x,y) = x^my^n, m,n \in \{0,1,2\dots \}.$ Thus both iterated integrals give the same answer for any polynomial in $x,y.$ Stone-Weierstass implies polynomials in $x,y$ are dense in $C([a,b]\times [c,d]).$ The result follows.